# select data from database using complicated query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm pretty new and I have to do complicated solution.
That is my database structure:

Table **users** contains `email, name`

table **connections** contains `followingemail, followedemail, isfollowedaccept`

table **location** included longitude, latitude, email.

I Want to get the email, the name, the longitude and the latitude of the users when I only have the email of the `followingemail` and where `isfollowedaccept` is true.

there can be values in `followingemail, followedemail` that appear more than once. SO there is more than one row that contains the same followingemail

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Microsoft Access (accdb file)

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
   SELECT u.email, u.name, l.longitude, l.latitude
    FROM users AS U
    INNER JOIN connections AS C ON u.email = c.followingemail 
    INNER JOIN location AS L ON L.email = u.email 
    WHERE c.isfollowedaccept = 'true'
```

You can read more about joins here : http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/

Comment: @tal what is the type of isfollowedaccept column? 
try to use double quotes instead of single ones.